# Visualization: Grouped and stacked Bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, visualization

I've got the following pands dataframe:

```
date    allocated_reason        allocated   bk_task

2019-10-27  AI               Allocated  1051
2019-11-03  AI               Allocated  1471
2019-10-27  Self Allocation      Allocated  291
2019-11-03  Self Allocation      Allocated  274
2019-11-10  Self Allocation      Allocated  40
2019-10-27  AI               Not Allocated  3570
2019-11-03  AI               Not Allocated  3267
2019-11-10  AI               Not Allocated  598
```

The date is the index and bk_tasks is the number of tasks for each combination: 
E.g. 1051 tasks in the week of 27/10 who are AI + Allocated.

I want to make a bar-plot witch has 2 bars for each week: 1 bar contains the number of not allocated tasks, the other the allocated task, and I want each bar to be grouped by AI or Self Allocation.

Comment: Please consider using underscores in your variables to make it easier to pick up your dataset using `pd.read_clipboard()`

Comment: I think the suggestion from AnandOCF was pretty good. If you think so too, please consider marking his suggestion as the accepted asnwer. By now you've also gained more than 15 reputation points and earned the privilige to award all questions and answers you find useful with your up-vote. I assure you all up-votes are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily render this with the help of following code:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(df, x="date", y="bk_task", color="allocated", barmode="group",
            facet_col="allocated_reason",color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.diverging.Tealrose[-2::-1])

fig.show()
```

[image]

With the help of faceting, you can easily group the allocated_reasoning column.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Nice one. It seems that this is the best available approach at the moment.

Comment: Glad, you found it useful